# window with id="Gradle" is already registered

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem since I updraged to Android Studio 3.1
I have an IDE Fatal error on launch : `window with id="Gradle" is already registered`

If the problem stopped there it would be ok, but then my project is never built correctly except if each time I clean it and then sync files from Gradle manually (and it seems so far not to be working all the time).

I tried many many things and ended up doing a complete clean install (removing all configuration files)... with no luck.

Has anyone ever ecountered this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may have the same problem : it was caused by the last Windows Update that changes OneDrive behavior, where I store some projects.

So you either move the projects outside of OneDrive, or deactive Files On Demande in OneDrive options.